# Java, parse raw, unconverted value of an xml attribute. Jaxson or jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

Given following XML input, how can I parse raw value of "descr" attribute?

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <declaration descr="&#xA0;"/>
```

I tried following with JAXB and Jackson. In both cases space is printed, while I expect

```
 &#xA0;
```

JaxB test:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "declaration")
public class DeclarationTestJaxb {

  @XmlAttribute
  private String descr;

  public String getDescr() {
      return descr;
  }

  public void setDescr(String descr) {
      this.descr = descr;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return descr;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller =  JAXBContext.newInstance(DeclarationTestJaxb.class).createUnmarshaller();
    System.out.println(unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test.xml")));
  }
}
```

I tried the same with  @JsonRawValue and @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true).
However the output is still converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. XML parsers always decode entities before returning strings.

Comment: And there's a reason for this: an application that tried to behave differently depending on how the attribute value was written would not be in keeping with the spirit of the XML specification, and would place unreasonable demands on the program generating the XML.